# Всех приветствую! Вопрос касательно SQL запросов

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

У меня есть две таблицы, причём все поля второй таблицы есть в первой (вторая таблица как бы является подмножеством первой), то что будет выводиться если нужно вывести все записи? Особенно по количествам строк вопрос. Например, вот такой запрос SELECT * FROM STEAK,PELMENY
При этом STEAK(meat_name, salt) и тут всего 7 записей, а PELMENY(meat_name, flour, salt, onion) тут 30 записей. Сколько в итоге в таком случае будет строк при выводе?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: *"Сколько в итоге в таком случае будет строк при выводе?"* --- ну ты выполни запрос и узнаешь.

Comment: *"вторая таблица как бы является подмножеством первой"*  --- пельмени - подмножество стейков...окей.. 

Comment: при таком запросе получите декартово произведение

Answer (score -1):

Ох... Количество строк = количество стейков * количество пельменей

Мне вот честно интересно, дла каких целей задан такой вопрос?